# Accessing the context of newly pushed object in array

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

What am I trying to achieve here is a structured data set for rendering a timeline from array named `"timeTree"`.

First I am iterating over goals, which have end date. Based on this date I want to *categorise* them into correct *year* and *month*.

Angular is being used for rendering and I had no problems with rendering this structure, same can't be said about creating it...

My question is how to add a goal into the year, which is not yet in the array?

```js
scope.timeTree = [];
_.each(goals, function(goal) {
    if (goal.stateId != "FINISHED") {

      var goalYear = new Date(goal.plannedEnd).getFullYear();
      var goalMonth = new Date(goal.plannedEnd).getMonth();

      if (scope.timeTree.length > 0) {
        _.each(scope.timeTree, function(year) {
          if (year.year === goalYear) {
            _.each(year.months, function(month) {
              if (month.month === goalMonth) {
                month.goals.push(goal);
              } else {
                year.months.push({
                  month: goalMonth,
                  goals: []
                });
                _.each(month.goals, function(goal) {

                })
              }
            })
          } else {
            scope.timeTree.push({
              year: goalYear,
              months: []
            });

            _.each(year.months, function(month) {
              if (month.month === goalMonth) {
                month.goals.push(goal);
              } else {

              }
            });
          }
        })
      } else {
        // init structure 
        scope.timeTree.push({
          year: goalYear,
          months: []
        });
        _.each(scope.timeTree, function(year) {

          year.months.push({
            month: goalMonth,
            goals: []
          });

          _.each(year.months, function(month) {

            month.goals.push(goal);


          });
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the code above, specifically, when year.year is not equal to goalYear, I simply don't know what to do...I am in the context of year ( object with information about the year, and months in that year, which have goals ) But I don't want to iterate over months in context of the year which is not equal to the year of the goal. I want to push goal into the months field in year I just pushed. Basically the main issue is with negative branches of if statements, when I have to push new objects into the array and in the same time push the goal into the arrays that were just created ( pushed ). Maybe this isn't even a good approach, so I am opened to better solutions. On the other hand, it would be nice, if you knew how to make this exact approach work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the deep nesting and iterations makes it easy to write confusing code. Unless there is a good reason to not use vanilla JS, it should be more than sufficient for the task at hand. Of course, writing the code without deep nesting should probably be the main priority here.

Example:

```
// In scope.timeTree, return me an array objects where it's year value matches goalYear
var matching_year = scope.timeTree.filter(function(yearly_goal) {
  return yearly_goal.year === goalYear;
});

// If it does not exists, create one
// Else, use that - there should only be 1
if (matching_year.length === 0) {
  var newTimeTree = {year: goalYear, months: []};
  matching_year = newTimeTree;
  scope.timeTree.push(newTimeTree);
} else {
  matching_year = matching_year[0];
}

// From the object with the matching year, find the object with the matching goalMonth
var matching_month = matching_year.months.filter(function(monthly_goal) {
  return monthly_goal.month === goalMonth;
});

// If it does not exists, create one
// Else, use that one
if (matching_month.length === 0) {
  var newGoal = {month: goalMonth, goals: []};
  matching_month = newGoal;
  matching_year.months.push(newGoal);
} else {
  matching_month = matching_month[0];
}

// Finally, pushed goal into the object that matches the year and the month
matching_month.goals.push(goal);
```

**Edit:** Of course, if you must, I noticed that you are using underscore.js for your _.each(list, iteratee). In that case, you can consider replacing vanilla JS' filter function for underscore JS' filter function as defined [here](http://underscorejs.org/#filter).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Map` (ES6 feature) to find the year and month you are looking for quickly (in constant time). And then use `Array.from` to convert that nested `Map` structure to the final one:

```js
var scope = {}; // for snippet only
// Sample data
var goals = [
    { plannedEnd: '2015-12-01', text: 'Break', stateId: 'STARTED' },
    { plannedEnd: '2016-07-01', text: 'Break', stateId: 'STARTED' },
    { plannedEnd: '2016-01-01', text: 'Year', stateId: 'STARTED' },
    { plannedEnd: '2016-01-01', text: 'New', stateId: 'STARTED' },
    { plannedEnd: '2015-12-01', text: 'Christmas', stateId: 'STARTED' },
    { plannedEnd: '2016-07-01', text: 'Summer', stateId: 'STARTED' },
];

scope.timeTree = Array.from(
    goals.filter( goal => goal.stateId != "FINISHED" )
        .reduce( (yearMap, goal) => {
            var goalYear = new Date(goal.plannedEnd).getFullYear();
            var goalMonth = new Date(goal.plannedEnd).getMonth();
            // Store year in map. Create new entry if not yet there
            if (!yearMap.has(goalYear)) yearMap.set(goalYear, new Map);
            var monthMap = yearMap.get(goalYear);
            // Same principle for month:
            if (!monthMap.has(goalMonth)) monthMap.set(goalMonth, []);
            monthMap.get(goalMonth).push(goal);
            return yearMap;
        }, new Map ), // Start with empty Map
    // Now convert to final structure, with second arg to main Array.from
    ([year, monthMap]) => ({ 
        year,
        months: Array.from(monthMap, ([month, goals]) => ({month, goals}))
            // Optionally sort months
            .sort( (a,b) => a.month - b.month )
    })
// Optionally sort the array by year
).sort( (a,b) => a.year - b.year );

  
console.log(scope.timeTree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help. The project I needed this for is built in es5, so using new javascript specification wasn't an option, but thanks nonetheless, I am definitely going to be using this in personal projects. KnightNiwrem, I had to keep references for rendering purposes, so instead of filter I used pick method from underscore. This is final solution.

```
_.each( value, function( goal ) {
                            if ( goal.stateId != "FINISHED" ){

                                var goalYear = new Date(goal.plannedEnd).getFullYear();
                                var goalMonth = new Date(goal.plannedEnd).getMonth();

                                var matchingYear = _.find( scope.timeTree,  function( year ){
                                    return year.year === goalYear;
                                })

                                if ( !!matchingYear ){
                                    var matchingMonth = _.find( matchingYear.months, function( month ){
                                        return month.month === goalMonth;
                                    })

                                    if ( !!matchingMonth ){
                                        matchingMonth.goals.push(goal);
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        matchingYear.months.push({ month: goalMonth, goals: [goal] });
                                    }
                                }
                                else{
                                    var newStructure = { year: goalYear,
                                                         months: [{ month: goalMonth, goals: [goal] }]
                                    }

                                    scope.timeTree.push(newStructure);
                                }
                            }
                        })
```